# How to compare two arraylist and enable toggle accordingly in android

Tags: android

I have an app in which listview with two arraylist suppose 1st "listStorage" and second is "existingDataSet" i have to compare these two arraylist value if found same then enable toggle of that index.

code:-

```
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<AllAppList> listStorage;
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<WhiteListModel> newDataSet, existingDataSet;
private String TAG = AppAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private MySharedPreference sharedPreference;
private WhiteListModel whiteListModel;
private Gson gson;

public AppAdapter(Context context, List<AllAppList> customizedListView) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listStorage = customizedListView;
    this.mContext = context;
    existingDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    newDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    gson = new Gson();
    sharedPreference = new MySharedPreference(mContext);
    whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();

    //retrieve data from shared preference
    String jsonScore = sharedPreference.getAppsArrayListData();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WhiteListModel>>() {
    }.getType();
    existingDataSet = gson.fromJson(jsonScore, type);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listStorage.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list_item, parent, false);

        listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
        listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        listViewHolder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());

    for (int i = 0; i<existingDataSet.size(); i++){
        for (int j= 0; j<listStorage.size(); j++){
            if (existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(listStorage.get(j).getPackName())){
                listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        //Adding items in Dataset
                        AllAppList appList = listStorage.get(position);
                        whiteListModel.setName(appList.getName());
                        whiteListModel.setPackName(appList.getPackName());


                        if (existingDataSet != null) {
                            existingDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                        } else {
                            newDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(newDataSet);
                        }
                        //Notifying adapter data has been changed.....
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }).show();

            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

/**
 * Save list of scores to own sharedpref
 *
 * @param whiteListApps
 */
private void saveScoreListToSharedpreference(ArrayList<WhiteListModel> whiteListApps) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //convert ArrayList object to String by Gson
    String jsonScore = gson.toJson(whiteListApps);
    Log.e(TAG, "LIST::" + jsonScore);
    //save to shared preference
    sharedPreference.saveAppsArrayListData(jsonScore);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    static SwitchCompat switchCompat;
    TextView textInListView;
    ImageView imageInListView;
}
```

}

Comment: Does it not work?

Comment: No....it does not work

Comment: where you have placed this piece of code? in getView()?

Comment: yes.................

Comment: can you post it?

Comment: Add .toString() after getPackName() and then try

Comment: See my adapter code

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < existingDataSet.size() ; i++){
        if (existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(listStorage.get(i).getPackName())){
            listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this? switch should retain its value false if not contains within 2 list when on getView because it trigger several times.

```
boolean isChecked = false
for (int i = 0; i<existingDataSet.size(); i++){
        for (int j= 0; j<listStorage.size(); j++){
            if (existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(listStorage.get(j).getPackName())){
               isChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }

 listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(isChecked);
```

Comment: This is enabling whole listview toggle

Comment: maybe some data in existingDataSet exist in listStorage

Comment: can you post data of 2 list?