# How to enable/disable toggle according to listview item index in android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain two arraylist namely "a" and "b" when I want to disable toggle button of items from arraylist "a" it automatically disable all other items in listview . Please help me out.

code of adapter:-

```
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<AllAppList> listStorage;
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<WhiteListModel> newDataSet, existingDataSet;
    private String TAG = AppAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private MySharedPreference sharedPreference;
    private WhiteListModel whiteListModel;
    private Gson gson;

    public AppAdapter(Context context, List<AllAppList> customizedListView) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listStorage = customizedListView;
        this.mContext = context;
        existingDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        newDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        gson = new Gson();
        sharedPreference = new MySharedPreference(mContext);
        whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();

        //retrieve data from shared preference
        String jsonScore = sharedPreference.getAppsArrayListData();
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WhiteListModel>>() {
        }.getType();
        existingDataSet = gson.fromJson(jsonScore, type);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listStorage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list_item, parent, false);

            listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
            listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            listViewHolder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        } else {
            listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
        listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());

        boolean isChecked = false;
        AllAppList model = listStorage.get(position);
        if (existingDataSet!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < existingDataSet.size(); i++) {
                if (model.getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName())) {
                    isChecked = true;

                }
            }
        }
        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(true);

        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Adding items in Dataset
                            AllAppList appList = listStorage.get(position);
                            whiteListModel.setName(appList.getName());
                            whiteListModel.setPackName(appList.getPackName());


                            if (existingDataSet != null) {
                                existingDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                                saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                            } else {
                                newDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                                saveScoreListToSharedpreference(newDataSet);
                            }
                            //Notifying adapter data has been changed.....
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }).show();
                }else {
                    listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(true);
                }



            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * Save list of scores to own sharedpref
     *
     * @param whiteListApps
     */
    private void saveScoreListToSharedpreference(ArrayList<WhiteListModel> whiteListApps) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //convert ArrayList object to String by Gson
        String jsonScore = gson.toJson(whiteListApps);
        Log.e(TAG, "LIST::" + jsonScore);
        //save to shared preference
        sharedPreference.saveAppsArrayListData(jsonScore);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        static SwitchCompat switchCompat;
        TextView textInListView;
        ImageView imageInListView;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use SparseBooleanArray for storing and retriveing state of position whether it is true or false. And set switchCompat accordingly.

Comment: can you edit my code plsss

Comment: I am new............

Comment: post your model class here

Comment: which one model of array 1 or model of array 2

Comment: model in which you are doing functionality for switchcompat

Comment: see my edited code

Comment: ACtually when app launch it get list of app installed in device and populate items in listview when i switch toggle to enable it will add items in other arraylist namely "whitList" and on secon launch i want to enable toggle of whitlist array and disable toggle of installed apps.

Comment: @Raghav, I don't understand what you are trying to explain by  "toggle button of items from arraylist "a" it automatically disable all other items". It is very unclear to me.

Comment: ACtually when app launch it get list of app installed in device and populate items in listview when i switch toggle to enable it will add items in other arraylist namely "whitList" and on secon launch i want to enable toggle of whitlist array and disable toggle of installed apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two arraylist and enable toggle accordingly in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232533/how-to-compare-two-arraylist-and-enable-toggle-accordingly-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Declare Boolean variable in WhiteListModel class. and write getter setter.

In your code add these lines.

```
private SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

In getView()

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list_item, parent, false);

            listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
            listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            listViewHolder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        } else {
            listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        **sparseBooleanArray.put(position,whiteListModel.getIsSwitchOn());**
        listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
        listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());

        boolean isChecked = false;
        AllAppList model = listStorage.get(position);
        if (existingDataSet!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < existingDataSet.size(); i++) {
                if (model.getPackName().equalsIgnoreCase(existingDataSet.get(i).getPackName())) {
                    isChecked = true;
                }
            }
        }
        **listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(whiteListModel.getIsSwitchOn());**

        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Adding items in Dataset
                            AllAppList appList = listStorage.get(position);
                            whiteListModel.setName(appList.getName());
                            whiteListModel.setPackName(appList.getPackName());

                            **whiteListModel.setIsSwitchOn(isChecked);**

                            if (existingDataSet != null) {
                                existingDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                                saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                            } else {
                                newDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                                saveScoreListToSharedpreference(newDataSet);
                            }
                            //Notifying adapter data has been changed.....
                            **listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(whiteListModel.getIsSwitchOn());**
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            **listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(whiteListModel.getIsSwitchOn());**
                        }
                    }).show();
                }else {
                    **listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(whiteListModel.getIsSwitchOn());**
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: I didnot understand where to put i already declare boolean in whiteList model

Comment: private String name;
    private String packName;
    private boolean isEnable;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPackName() {
        return packName;
    }

    public void setPackName(String packName) {
        this.packName = packName;
    }

    public boolean isEnable() {
        return isEnable;
    }

    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        isEnable = enable;
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you used a ***static*** component in ViewHolder ,it means you want to create only one instance of that object. 
So, in this case all buttons are only ONE Button.If you change each property of each row ,It will be change in all rows.

Use this viewHolder instead of your "viewHolder"

```
private class ViewHolder {
        SwitchCompat switchCompat;
        TextView textInListView;
        ImageView imageInListView;
    }
```

Comment: You used a static SwitchCompat. You have not use static component in ViewHolder. Did you try it without static expression?